# Upgrading docker without affecting running containers

Tags: docker

Currently I am running Docker version 0.6.6 and I am planning to upgrade that to the latest version.

I am worried that when I do that I would be required to restart the running daemon and that would in turn kill all my running containers.

Can someone please help me upgrade the version without affecting the containers or point me to a documentation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It definitely will. I can only advise using docker cluster such as CoreOS.

Even there you will have to stop docker containers but the point of dockerizing your infrastructure should be that you don't care if one instance of your [app](http://12factor.net/) will fail. CoreOS's fleet should take care of starting new container.

I am sorry but I don't have answer that would solve your current problem, maybe someone will.